# How can I pair one div class to different CSS image style properties

Tags: html, css, image, properties

I am struggling with how I can place my CSS style code from my HTML into my CSS stylesheet. I am using 1 picture with different characters and the CSS im using will perfectly cut the image into different characters with the CSS behind the div class "spelers". Should I add an ID to my class or?

Over here my code

```
  <div class="spelers_lijn1" id="spelers_lijn_1">
            <div class="stang"></div>
            <div class="spelers" style="left:162px;background-position:35px 0px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="spelers_lijn2" id="spelers_lijn_2">
            <div class="stang"></div>
            <div class="spelers" style="left:92px;background-position:0 0"></div>
            <div class="spelers" style="left:232px;background-position:-35px 0"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="spelers_lijn3" id="spelers_lijn_3">
            <div class="stang"></div>
            <div class="spelers" style="left:112px;background-position:-70px 0"></div>
            <div class="spelers" style="left:212px;background-position:-105px 0"></div>
        </div>
```

```
.spelers {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 69px;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(../images/spelers.png);
}
```

Over here the image im using https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Xwp.jpg

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I followed this tutorial and Im rebuilding this project. https://codepen.io/mohamedmustafaali/pen/vRMWGa

Comment: @KimKakanAndersson So im trying to remove the CSS code from the HTML file towards the CSS stylesheet

Comment: Yes but if you insert your code in JsFiddle you'll find out that the canvas is blank. We need a working example.

Comment: Over here a working example on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnwafmz6/4/ @KimKakanAndersson